# Applying style to text from database

Tags: html, mysql, css

I'm having a bit of trouble styling some text that is being gathered from a database. Is there a quick way of stylizing the article content inside?

This is where I have it being pulled from the database

```
<div class="col-4 col-fright">
<h1 class="article_title"><?=$this->article->name?></h1>
<?=$this->article->content?>

<?if(count($this->siblings) > 0){?>
<hr>
<strong>You may also be interested in these articles:</strong><br>
<?foreach($this->siblings as $s){?> 
    <a href="<?=BASE_URL?>/help/article/name/<?=$s->slug?>"><?=$s->name?></a><br>
<?}?>
<?}?>
</div>
```

I figured I could just throw a span class around the article content but that would apply the style to all the text.

Here's an example of what the text may look like when I pull it

[image: Example of text being pulled]

The title looks fine since I was able to put it into a tag, but everything else is needs work.

Comment: 1. Don't use PHP short tags. 2. What do you mean? You style text from a database the same as you would style text from any other source...

Comment: I have to use PHP tags. I can't edit the information I'm pulling, it's what we get from 'the other guys'. So the tag this->article->content is what I have to work with...at least to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: PHP short tags omit the `<?php` in favor of `<?=`. Best practices recommend against their use. It's still not clear (to me) what text you are talking about styling or why you can't apply CSS to it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a quick way. I suppose you could start by looking for the first occurrence of "[more]" and either removing it or properly formatting the content to show the rest of the article once [more] is clicked.

There's not much you can do unless you are reasonably confident about the structure of your source. For example, applying some logic like "if the number of works on a line are fewer than 7 and contain no periods, wrap it in  tags" would produce sub-headers in this example, but might break in others that have unpredictable content.

It seems as though you're looking for artificial intelligence to format your document.